# Вставка переменной php в html

Tags: php, html

```
$check_users=mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT `firstname`,`lastname` FROM `users` WHERE `id`=2");
$check_users=mysqli_fetch_assoc($check_users);
$firstname=$check_users['firstname'];
$lastname=$check_users['lastname'];

print '<li><h2 class="item__user" href="#">'$lastname' '$firstname'</h2></li>';
```

Всем привет! Как вставить переменные `$lastname` и `$firstname` в тег 'li'. (Вывод который там есть-не работает ).

Comment: `>' . $lastname . ' ' . $firstname . '<` советую почитать https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.operators.string.php

Comment: @ArchDemon , спасибо большое)

Answer (score 1):

```
print "<li><h2 class='item__user' href='#'>{$lastname} {$firstname}</h2></li>";
```

---

Советую про конкатенацию и отличие одинарных и двойных кавычек в PHP почитать. Замените строку, эта будет работать.

Answer (score 1):

так же можно сделать и так

```
echo "<li><h2 class='item__user' href='#'>" . $lastname . " " . $firstname "</h2></li>";
```

Comment: В двойных кавычках, переменные будут и без конкатенации интерпретироваться.

Comment: согласен, мой завтык

Answer (score 0):

Документация по [heredoc](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)

```
<?php

$firstname = 'Имя';
$lastname = 'Фамилия';

echo <<<EOT
<li>
    <h2 class="item__user" href="#">{$lastname} {$firstname}</h2>
</li>
EOT;
```